# Can be the `last` command disabled?

Tags: log, last-command

I don't want to make the log of logins accessible. How do I disable/cancel logging data available through the `last` command?

Comment: Any question should always include what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: I *think* it can be done by passing `nowtmp` to the `pam_lastlog` module - but I haven't tried it